# Please don't close questions from new members without explaining

Tags: discussion

Example:

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/113214/can-teflon-overheat-on-low

That question, from a brand-new member, got two close votes (because of the medical aspects, I'm pretty sure) without anyone commenting to explain what the member did wrong.  Please, let's keep SA a welcoming place by only closing new members' questions *after* educating them.

Editing to add a second example, from today: [Gochugaru powder vs paste?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/113870/gochugaru-powder-vs-paste)

Thanks!

Comment: For that specific example, please also be careful about the distinction between safety and health. As far as I can tell, that question was in the former category, and shouldn't have gotten any close votes in the first place. I don't think I should undo anything because it's been deleted by the OP and that's not necessarily because of the close votes, but... yeah, being welcoming also includes only closing questions that the rules say we need to close.

Comment: Added a 2nd example, mostly to bump this discussion.  SA is becoming a new-poster-hostile place.  Questions get closed without ever trying to help new posters.  It didn't used to be like this.